# Duplicates in BigQuery tables after ingesting data from Postgresql/AWS

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

We have a Postgresql DB hosted in AWS. If I query it with psql, or python libraries, or tableau, the rows match up.

But I want to be able to use it in BigQuery and I'm seeing duplicate rows for some of the tables. I didn't create the BigQuery connection, but the people who did are always busy so I thought of lending a hand, but I'm super lost as to what I should look out for here.

I know the issue is not the PostgreSQL DB itself, otherwise, the row counts in psql/python/etc wouldn't match.

So the issue is how the data is being ingested in BigQuery. I wanted to know what could be your suggestions in order to get rid of this as best as I can.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate a simple way to identify duplicates-

```
select distinct * from table.location
```

Of course, if there are any auto-incrementing columns you'll need to ignore them (replace `*` with the columns ingested from Postgres).

Then just create a new table from the results once verified-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE new_table.location
AS
SELECT
DISTINCT *
FROM table.location
group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you Ian. This means to make the de-duplication post-ingestion, right? Is there a way this can happen pre-ingestion?

Comment: That's right. I am not sure how to tell you about pre-ingestion without knowing how the ingestion is occurring. If using a standard connector I doubt this would be an issue, but couldn't say for sure.